# Eclipse Can't Open Servlet in Browser

Tags: java, eclipse, web, servlets

I just finish making my first servlet and it won't load in the web browser. I didn't choose to use the web.xml file.  Here's the code:

'''

```
package myFirstServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

'''

Here's a screenshot of my project not loading.  I'm tearing my hair out.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What's at the bottom of the Console output, or where ever the server output is for around the time of the 404 in the client?

Comment: I can see that your Servlet is in the MyFirstServlet package.  Did you put your Servlet in a folder named MyFirstServlet  inside of the classes folder? Is  MyFirstServlet the name of your web app as well?